# What are these sets of three numbers in my Minecraft server log?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm referring to the floating-point-esque numbers in parentheses that appear after the entity ID, at the end of the lines indicating that a player has logged in:

```
2011-04-21 23:49:37 [INFO] burpen [/192.168.1.2:45001] logged in with entity id 120884 at (26.5, 118.62000000476837, 72.5)
2011-04-21 23:49:45 [INFO] burpen [/192.168.1.2:45006] logged in with entity id 121098 at (25.5, 118.62000000476837, 83.5)
2011-04-21 23:49:53 [INFO] burpen [/192.168.1.2:45013] logged in with entity id 121638 at (20.5, 72.62000000476837, 79.5)
```

I believe these started appearing after the 1.5 server update, or one of the updates since then. I initially thought they denoted player location at time of login, but they don't match up with the values shown when I press F3 immediately after logging in. Moreover, the numbers change even when the player doesn't move (the three example lines were generated by standing in the same spot and repeatedly logging in/out).

I realize they might be part of some internal testing at Mojang that was left in for the most recent update(s), and in that case, they might not be terribly important. But if otherwise, I'm curious to see if anyone knows what these are.

Comment: I would've answered with "player coordinates", but it's interesting you said that they didn't match up.

Comment: I would have said coordinates too.

Comment: Sometimes, lag can cause players to jump around as they're logging in or teleporting.  Could that be it?

Comment: Where you at the exact same place on logins?

Comment: @Maxpm I doubt it-- the lag in my case should be very minimal as the server is running on the same physical machine (and therefore the same subnet) as the client.

Comment: @M'vy Yes, I was in the same place. I didn't touch the movement keys, just logged in/out multiple times.

Comment: Year, month, day

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are absolutely player coordinates — the `.62` in the middle (`y`) coordinate is a dead giveaway.  If you check your position using <kbd>F3</kbd> while standing on any full block, you'll see your `y` coordinate **always** ends in `.62000…` (or occasionally `.619999…`).  This is because the player's coordinates are reported from the "eyes" — the point where the camera sits in first-person view.  A player's eyes are `1.62` blocks/meters above the ground.

Now, as to why they aren't *accurate*, I couldn't say.  My best guess is that it's related to the "spawn radius" in SMP.  When you die (or log in for the first time), you don't spawn at a fixed point in the world; there is about a chunk-sized area in which you can appear.  It's possible that, when a returning player is added to the world, they are either initially placed in the spawn zone before being moved to their real location, or alternatively that the spawn radius is applied to their entry coordinates and reported in the log, but discarded before the player fully enters the world.

***Update:*** A bugfix listed in [Notch's blog post](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/5775170768/the-changelist-for-1-6) on the changes coming in 1.6 supports this theory:

- *Fixed players spawning in the wrong location and quickly lerping to the correct location*

*("Lerping" refers to linear interpolation, the type of math which controls player movement.)*